# Use of の vs か in questions

Tags: grammar, word-choice, questions

i’ve seen japanese speakers switch between both の and か in the same conversation or situation. are there certain phrases where it’s better to use one or the other? for example is の better to use with だ and か better with です? what are the guidelines for choosing which to use?